# Create VM in Azure Java SDK

Tags: java, azure, sdk, automation, azure-storage

Following the Azure Java SDK Github page.

```
        VirtualMachine windowsVM = azure.virtualMachines().define(windowsVmName)
                .withRegion(region)
                .withExistingResourceGroup(rgName)
                .withNewPrimaryNetwork("10.0.0.0/28")
                .withPrimaryPrivateIpAddressDynamic()
                .withNewPrimaryPublicIpAddress(pipDnsLabelWindowsVM)
                .withPopularWindowsImage(KnownWindowsVirtualMachineImage.WINDOWS_SERVER_2012_R2_DATACENTER)
                .withAdminUsername(firstWindowsUserName)
                .withAdminPassword(firstWindowsUserPassword)
                .withSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.STANDARD_D3_V2)
                .defineNewExtension(windowsCustomScriptExtensionName)
                    .withPublisher(windowsCustomScriptExtensionPublisherName)
                    .withType(windowsCustomScriptExtensionTypeName)
                    .withVersion(windowsCustomScriptExtensionVersionName)
                    .withMinorVersionAutoUpgrade()
                    .withPublicSetting("fileUris", windowsScriptFileUris)
                    .withPublicSetting("commandToExecute", installMySQLWindowsCommand)
                    .attach()
                .create();
```

There is no information on if we want to use a static ip for example or a different extension like a security extension

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a VM and assign a static ip via using Azure Java SDK.

Please refer to these samples of the name started with `CreateVirtualMachine` on GitHub [page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/azure-samples/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/samples). Meanwhile, according to the javadocs of Azure Java SDK, you can refer to the two interfaces [`NetworkInterface.DefinitionStages.WithPrimaryPrivateIp`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/network/NetworkInterface.DefinitionStages.WithPrimaryPrivateIp.html) & [`NetworkInterface.DefinitionStages.WithPrimaryPublicIpAddress`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/network/NetworkInterface.DefinitionStages.WithPrimaryPublicIpAddress.html) to set up the static IP via the methods, such as [`withPrimaryPrivateIpAddressStatic(String staticPrivateIpAddress)`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/network/NetworkInterface.DefinitionStages.WithPrimaryPrivateIp.html#withPrimaryPrivateIpAddressStatic-java.lang.String-).

Hope it helps. Any concern, please improve your description and feel free to let me know.

Comment: Actually I am trying to create a VM from an existing network and existing network security group .. but I always fail at .create ?!